# Points and Segments in Java

Tags: java, line, segment

I have created a Point class and a Segment class. I am trying to find a way to determine if a given point is part of the line segment, by using the absolute difference from the beginning point to the ending point of the segment. It has to be smaller than 0.01, so then the point Is part of my line. 
I have to do that using a contains method. I am giving you my code below.
I am beginner. I know I have to do it using only one parameter in the contains method (Point p) but I can't do it right.

```
`public boolean contains(Point p){
    segment1x = currentPoint.pointX - point1.pointX;
    segment1y = currentPoint.pointY - point1.pointY;

    segment2x = point2.pointX - point1.pointX;
    segment2y = point2.pointY - point1.pointY;

    absoluteDifference = Math.abs((segment1x*segment2y)-(segment1y*segment2x));

    if(absoluteDifference !=0){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}`
```

Comment: Why don't you use `p` parameter? Is it a typo?

Comment: How to use the p parameter? I don't understand. The problem is (I think) that in this code, I have to have 2 differents points, in order to determine the difference. But I am asked to use only one point as parameter. So it's wrong.

Comment: you actually do not need 2 points to be passed as the parameters. You need to determine if `p` is part of the segment

Comment: I understand that I just don't see what's wrong or how can I change my code to do it. Because all the elements here are referring to 2 points. I have been trying it since yesterday and only now I saw I only need 1 point, but I can't change it correctly.

Comment: I think there's confusion because you've specified a `Point p` as a parameter, that you're not using. You're using `currentPoint`, but what is that? You're also using `point1` and `point2`. What are those?

Comment: I will try and change this. I should be using currentpoint which I'm not, I think.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "segment". Do you mean that you just want to know if a point touches or is close "enough" to a line drawn between two other points? If I was to implement a solution, I'd start making sure my math was sound. (I'm not saying yours isn't, but that's the first thing I'd need to check)

Comment: My math is sound, I just think I can't express it properly in english, sorry. I just want to know if a given point belongs to a line segment i've created. I don't know If I'm making sense.

Comment: Can you edit your question and show an example of your math using just math? With points and calculations?

Answer (score 0):

Determine the slope intercept equation of the line defined by the two segment points.
Then determine if the point is on the line.
Then determine if the point lies between the two segment points.

```
public class Segment {
    private Point point1;
    private Point point2;

    // the equation of a line = y=mx+b, this is called the slope intercept
    // m is the slope and b is the y-intercept (the point where x is 0 on the line)

    public Segment(Point point1, Point point2) {
        if (point1 == null || point2 == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot have null point(s).");
        }
        this.point1 = point1;
        this.point2 = point2;
    }

    public Point getPoint1() {
        return point1;
    }

    public Point getPoint2() {
        return point2;
    }

    public double getSlope() {
        double diffX = point2.getX() - point1.getX();
        double diffY = point2.getY() - point1.getY();
        return diffY / diffX;
    }

    public double getIntercept() {
        // if y=mx+b then b=y-mx
        return point1.getY() - getSlope() * point1.getX;
    }

    public boolean contains(Point p){
        double m = getSlope();
        double b = getIntercept();

        // now we use our slope intercept formula to find if the given point 
        // is on the line 
        double calculatedY = m * p.getX() + b;
        if (calculatedY == p.getY()) {
            // if we get here then the point is on the line
            // now we have to test if the point is between the segment ends
            double biggerX = Math.max(point1.getX(), point2.getX());
            double smallerX = Math.min(point1.getX(), point2.getX());
            double biggerY = Math.max(point1.getY(), point2.getY());
            double smallerY = Math.min(point1.getY(), point2.getY());
            if ((p.getX() >= smallerX && p.getX() <= biggerX)
                && (p.getY() >= smallerY && p.getY() <= biggerY)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    } // end contains(Point p)
} // end class Segment
```

Comment: I would have thought it was `(the point where x is 0 on the line)`

Comment: Thank you. I am currently making some changes of  my own, but I will check the code you give here too. I'm just trying to figure it out on my own. Can I post the new code I wrote for you to take a look?